# Application environment guidelines

Tags: windows, winforms, desktop-application

I am looking for Windows applications guidelines, related to configuration, log files and other issues not related to user experience - like

- Store your configs in Foo directory
- Put temporary files in Baz one
- Default directory for open/save has to be Bar
- etc

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the **Windows 7 Client Software Logo Program Documentation**. http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/E/9/1E9580D9-2B2B-499C-918A-C9BA5EAC4A32/Windows%207%20Client%20Software%20Logo.pdf

> The purpose of this document is to
>   outline the technical requirements and
>   eligibility qualifications an
>   application must meet in order to
>   participate in the Windows 7 Client
>   Software Logo Program. The Windows
>   platform has a broad ecosystem of
>   products and partners that supports
>   the platform. Displaying the Windows
>   logo on your product represents a
>   relationship and a shared commitment
>   to quality between Microsoft and your
>   company. Customers trust that seeing
>   the Windows brand on your product
>   ensures that it meets compatibility
>   standards and performs well on the
>   Windows platform.   The Windows 7
>   Client Software Logo Program is made
>   up of policies and technical
>   requirements to help ensure that
>   third-party applications carrying the
>   Windows brand are both easy to install
>   and reliable on PCs running Windows 7.
>   End users and customers value
>   stability, reliability, performance,
>   and quality in the systems they
>   purchase. Microsoft  focuses some of
>   its investments to meet these
>   requirements for software applications
>   designed to run on the Windows 7
>   platform for PCs. These efforts
>   include compatibility tests for
>   ease-of-use, better performance, and
>   enhanced security on PCs running
>   Windows 7 software. Microsoft
>   compatibility tests have been designed
>   in collaboration with industry
>   partners and are continuously improved
>   in response to industry developments
>   and consumer demand.

Answer (score 1):

A good point to start is the [Windows 7 Logo Requirements](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9668061), which define the requirements to qualify for the Windows 7 logo.

The folders to be used are for instance defined in point 2 of the Technical Requirements ("Install to the correct folders by default" with exact information about what to put where).